# Is it true that,$ \|f\|^p_{L_p} \le 2^{p-1}\|u'\|^p_{L_p}+2^{p-1}|u(\zeta)|^p $?

Tags: inequality, lp-spaces

Is it true that,$$
\|f\|^p_{L_p} \le 2^{p-1}\|f'\|^p_{L_p}+2^{p-1}|f(\zeta)|^p
$$

for $f$ is $C^1$ in $[0,1]$ and $\zeta$ in [0,1]

Comment: Did you mean $\lVert u\rVert_{L_p}^p$ on the left?

Comment: Just use the most trivial bound $\|f\|_{C}\le |f(\zeta)|+\|f'\|_{L^1}$ combined with Holder and such (assuming $p\ge 1$, of course)

Comment: How to get the trivial bound?

Answer (score 1):

You can write $f(x)= f(\xi)+\int_{\xi}^xf'(s)ds$ for $0\leq \xi<x\leq 1$ and then you can proceed. Also you will need the elementary inequality $(a+b)^p\leq 2^{p-1}(a^2+b^2)$.